# Best noSQL to just insert and fetch massive data

Tags: database, azure, nosql

My requirement is just, i need to store a massive data (round about 50k records) in a single call and fetch that data in single call too. Which noSQL category will be best. Also that category should be best compatible with Microsoft azure.

Comment: Please explain it properly what is problem and what did you research on it.

Comment: what is your problem ??

Comment: I am confused, which nosql to use that best matches my requirements i-e i need to store a large number of records at a time and to fetch that large amount, no edit, no update no delete.